# AJAX action returning empty posts array?

Tags: ajax

I've created an action for an AJAX request to trigger.  On the site, the action is successfully triggered.  However, when I run this in the action:

```
$posts = get_posts();
```

The post array always returns empty.

This is how I am adding the action:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_home_load_more', 'home_load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_home_load_more', 'home_load_more');
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Use `WP_Query` and pass explicit arguments to the query, if it still doesn't work you can at least inspect the query object to see what's going on.

Comment: have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? It's a lot harder to run into problems like this and you get a free posts endpoint out of the box!

Comment: Btw could you please add the `home_load_more` function to your question? It can't be answered the way right now it is.